# how to embeddingvector word embedding?

Tags: word-embedding

I read a paper "Integrating and Evaluating Neural Word Embeddings
in Information Retrieval".

I tried to understand a source code and when opening the file named:
vectors_ap8889_skipgram_s200_w20_neg20_hs0_sam1e-4_iter5

I found a word vector representation like this:
downtown "-0.465147 -0.049099 -0.023432 0.058986 -0.085395 -0.027324 -0.050315 ................................................"

Please; I need you to explain what do these values mean and which term refer in the corpus and how can I obtain it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and update your question according:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The numbers don't have an intrinsic meaning. It's just a n-dimensional embedding of the given words.

If the embedding is done correctly you should see similar words having embedding close together. For example "good" should be closer to "awesome" than to "island".

The common way to use it is to convert the words into their embedding space and use that as an input to some machine learning problem. The advantage is that the embedding is trained on a lot more data than you have for your problem so the embedding offer a shortcut to training your model.